# Echo PHP variable as an value of input field

Tags: php, html

I have a simple HTML form with multiple input tags. On page load i provide data to the form to echo the current value of field from database and than user can modify those values and submit again to perform an update.

```
<input type="text" name="nameMember" id="nameMember" value=<?php echo (isset($nameMember)) ? $nameMember: ''?>>
```

Code works fine except that it do not display complete variable.

For example, If $nameMember = 'Saurabh Pradhan' than instead of showing 'Saurabh Pradhan' as value of input tag it only shows 'Saurabh'.

If i remove the space from the data and make it to 'SaurabhPradhan' it displays complete name. Basically it is only removing the text after space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML attribute values should generally be wrapped in quotes:

```
<input type="text" name="nameMember" id="nameMember" value="<?php echo (isset($nameMember)) ? $nameMember: ''?>">
```

exactly as you already do with the `type` and `name` attributes

The `value` attribute is no different

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add quotes in value attribute like value="" in quotes echo your variable ,in HTML quotes generate automatically and if space found attribute automatically close quotes after space

```
 value="<?php echo (isset($nameMember)) ? $nameMember: ''?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around your echo

```
value="<?php echo (isset($nameMember)) ? $nameMember: ''?>"
```